# Worklight Failed to Start (Mac)

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst

The following error occurs when I start worklight:

```
objc[732]: Class JavaLaunchHelper is implemented in both /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/bin/java and /Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_40.jdk/Contents/Home/jre/lib/libinstrument.dylib. One of the two will be used. Which one is undefined.
Launching worklight (WebSphere Application Server 8.5.5.0/wlp-1.0.3.20130524-0951) on Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, version 1.7.0_40-b43 (en_US)
[AUDIT   ] CWWKE0001I: The server worklight has been launched.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0058I: Monitoring dropins for applications. 
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://acab0a7a.ipt.aol.com:10080/_MobileBrowserSimulator/
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application _MobileBrowserSimulator started in 0.274 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKT0016I: Web application available (default_host): http://acab0a7a.ipt.aol.com:10080/mobile/
[err] 22  WorklightPU  WARN   [Scheduled Executor-thread-1] openjpa.Runtime - An error occurred while registering a ClassTransformer with PersistenceUnitInfo: name 'WorklightPU', root URL [file:/Users/thomas/Documents/workspace/Concert/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar]. The error has been consumed. To see it, set your openjpa.Runtime log level to TRACE. Load-time class transformation will not be available.
[ERROR   ] FWLST0003E: ========= Failed starting project /mobile [project mobile]
Error creating bean with name 'taskManager' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/Users/thomas/Documents/workspace/Concert/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'worklightAuthenticationService' while setting bean property 'authenticationService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'worklightAuthenticationService' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/Users/thomas/Documents/workspace/Concert/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'com.worklight.core.auth.impl.LoginConfigurationServiceBean#eb508f3' of type [com.worklight.core.auth.impl.LoginConfigurationServiceBean] while setting bean property 'loginConfigurationService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.worklight.core.auth.impl.LoginConfigurationServiceBean#eb508f3' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/Users/thomas/Documents/workspace/Concert/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Class 'com.customauthpackage.CustomLoginModule' defined in login module 'CustomLoginModule' in the authentication configuration file doesn't exist.
[ERROR   ] SRVE0283E: Exception caught while initializing context: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'taskManager' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/Users/thomas/Documents/workspace/Concert/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'worklightAuthenticationService' while setting bean property 'authenticationService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'worklightAuthenticationService' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/Users/thomas/Documents/workspace/Concert/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'com.worklight.core.auth.impl.LoginConfigurationServiceBean#eb508f3' of type [com.worklight.core.auth.impl.LoginConfigurationServiceBean] while setting bean property 'loginConfigurationService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.worklight.core.auth.impl.LoginConfigurationServiceBean#eb508f3' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/Users/thomas/Documents/workspace/Concert/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Class 'com.customauthpackage.CustomLoginModule' defined in login module 'CustomLoginModule' in the authentication configuration file doesn't exist.
Caused by (repeated) ... : org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'taskManager' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/Users/thomas/Documents/workspace/Concert/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Cannot resolve reference to bean 'worklightAuthenticationService' while setting bean property 'authenticationService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'worklightAuthenticationService' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/Users/thomas/Documents/workspace/Concert/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Cannot create inner bean 'com.worklight.core.auth.impl.LoginConfigurationServiceBean#eb508f3' of type [com.worklight.core.auth.impl.LoginConfigurationServiceBean] while setting bean property 'loginConfigurationService'; nested exception is org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'com.worklight.core.auth.impl.LoginConfigurationServiceBean#eb508f3' defined in URL [wsjar:file:/Users/thomas/Documents/workspace/Concert/WorklightServerConfig/shared/resources/worklight-jee-library-6.0.0.jar!/conf/core.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.RuntimeException: Class 'com.customauthpackage.CustomLoginModule' defined in login module 'CustomLoginModule' in the authentication configuration file doesn't exist.
... 
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Class 'com.customauthpackage.CustomLoginModule' defined in login module 'CustomLoginModule' in the authentication configuration file doesn't exist.
...
[AUDIT   ] CWWKZ0001I: Application mobile started in 4.168 seconds.
[AUDIT   ] CWWKF0011I: The server worklight is ready to run a smarter planet.
```

I'm running OS X (10.8.4), Eclipse Juno SR2 20130225-0426, worklight plugin version 6.0.0.20130724-1819, Eclipse is pointing to jdk1.7.0_40 ("MacOS X VM") running in 1.7 compiler compliance level. CustomLoginModule is on the server and in the Eclipse viewer its covered in odd errors such as "String cannot be resolved to a type". I had this same error in windows and I believe I fixed it when I switched the eclipse jdk, but that didn't help this time. I really think this is a jdk issue, but everything seems correct. Any ideas? Thanks

EDIT: I resolved the issue by right clicking my project > properties > Java Build Path > Libraries > editing that "JRE System Library [jre7] (unbound)" and selecting "Workspace default JRE (Home)" thanks for your help! I got another problem now, but this one looks familiar as well. –

Comment: Please write your solution as an answer so that others could know it as well.

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked for updates to your installed Worklight plug-in? a fix for 6.0.0.0 was released a while ago. Please check.

Otherwise, and I am not entirely sure, you should perhaps do the following:

1. Right-click on the Worklight project >> Properties
2. Java Build Path >> Libraries >> Add Library >> Server Runtime
3. Choose "Worklight Development Server" >> OK
4. Clean >> Restart server

Comment: I updated my worklight plugin yesterday, I believe it is the latest.
On other note, I checked the project's build path and checked the libraries and I notice that jre7 says "JRE System Library [jre7] (unbound)" and there is a red x on the icon. At the top there's a warning that says: Build path entry is missing: org.eclipse.jdt.launching.JRE_CONA...R/org.eclipse.jdt.internal.debug.ui.launcher.StandardVMType/jre7

Comment: I resolved the issue by editting that "JRE System Library [jre7] (unbound)" and selecting "Workspace default JRE (Home)" thanks for your help! I got another problem now, but this one looks familiar as well.

Comment: @JonathanSweetman, can you write this as a new answer and mark it as Answered?